# Chrome Extensão x Delphi

Tags: javascript, delphi, google-chrome

Alguém sabe como comunicar uma extensão criada para o CHROME com o DELPHI ?

Algo como enviar comandos do DELPHI para essa extensão OU vice-versa ?

Segue o código extensão que captura o código da ABA ATUAL.

```
function DOMtoString(document_root) {
    var html = '',
        node = document_root.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        switch (node.nodeType) {
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            html += node.outerHTML;
            break;
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
            html += node.nodeValue;
            break;
        case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
            html += '<![CDATA[' + node.nodeValue + ']]>';
            break;
        case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
            html += '<!--' + node.nodeValue + '-->';
            break;
        case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
            // (X)HTML documents are identified by public identifiers
            html += "<!DOCTYPE " + node.name + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '') + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '') + '>\n';
            break;
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    return html;
}

chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: DOMtoString(document)
});
```

Comment: Explique melhor. É um servidor externo escrito em Delphi? É um programa rodando na maquina do cliente ao mesmo tempo que o chrome?

Comment: Criei uma extensão para o CHROME que captura em TEMPO REAL o código fonte do navegador, através de uma função JAVASCRIPT. Agora preciso fazer o DELPHI pegar essa função e jogar em um MEMO ou algo relacionado, não sei se da para fazer isso, mais se der, o interesse do projeto seria esse.

Comment: Coloquei o código acima Amigo..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não está claro se quer comunicar com um programa escrito em Delphi na maquina local ou remotamente sob a internet. Em todo o caso a solução está em abrir um servidor HTTP pelo Delphi e lidar com requisições geradas pela extensão. Na extensão você pode enviar uma requisição POST para o IP da máquina que está rodando o programa Delphi (`127.0.0.1` se for o próprio computador). O servidor pode ser uma aplicação CGI, por exemplo, escutando em alguma porta específica que a extensão conheça. Essa é a ideia básica.

Me parece que não há outros meios (até por motivos de segurança) de a extensão acessar alguma coisa do computador, seja o que for. A única forma de comunicação seria com AJAX mesmo.

Comment: Será um programa rodando na própria máquina do cliente sim, tudo localhost. Vou ter um FORM DELPHI com um MEMO. Preciso que o CHROME se conecte a esse form em tempo real e envie o source code do html na aba atual (no caso a minha função javascript), pode ser até mesmo através de ServerSocket ou algo relacionado.

Comment: @user7605 então o que eu falei responde ao problema. É só você partir para a implementação agora. Não deve haver dificuldade a partir daqui. Mas se houver crie uma nova pergunta para atender à dificuldade específica que encontrar enquanto implementa.

Comment: OK Amigo, obrigado pela ajuda, já estou na internet estudando isso.